# Insert UTC date in Date type column

Tags: sql-server, date, utc

I want to insert UTC Date into my SQL Server table date type, my query is failing and here is my that fails

```
Insert into Vendor(Vendor_id,Vendor_Name,LIC_START_DATE) 
             VALUES('12345','XYZ','2020-01-01Z');
```

`LIC_START_DATE` is date type.

Could you please help on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is failing" - does it give an error? Not turn up? Turn up wrong? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Insert into Vendor(Vendor_id,Vendor_Name,LIC_START_DATE) 
             VALUES('12345','XYZ','2020-01-01Z');
```

Try

```
Insert into Vendor(Vendor_id,Vendor_Name,LIC_START_DATE) 
             VALUES('12345','XYZ','2020-01-01');
```

About UTC date/datetime in general:

To get the current UTC date:

```
select getutcdate();
```

To get the current UTC datetime2(7)

```
select sysutcdatetime()
```

To translate an existing datetime in a particular time zone to UTC datetime

```
declare @existing_date          datetime='2001-01-01 10:00:00';

select @existing_date at time zone 'Eastern Standard Time' at time zone 'UTC';
```